# Avoid System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in PresentationCore.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I know there are other questions about this already, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem in them.

I am pretty new to WPF and I am building media player which also includes displaying images. One of the options is to tile image. That is done like this:

```
private void TilePic(string path) {
    var containerWidth = MyMainWindow.Width;
    double xPos = 0;
    double yPos = 0;
    Image image = null;
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path.Replace("/", "\\")));
    while (yPos < MyMainWindow.Height) {
        while (xPos < MyMainWindow.Width) {
            image = new Image();
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(image, imageSource);
            image.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            image.Width = imageSource.Width;
            image.Height = imageSource.Height;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(image);
            xPos += imageSource.Width;
        }
        xPos = 0;
        yPos += imageSource.Height;
    }
}
```

And for one specific gif image (3,13 MB 200 x 196), after function completes I am receiving. Image is small, but long and for 1920x1080 screen, this adds ~50 images.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap.CopyCommon(RenderTargetBitmap sourceBitmap)
```

Image is small, but long and for 1920x1080 screen, this adds ~50 images.

I red that it's about too many GDI handles. With GDIView I can see that it has ~7000 region handles. Can someone tell me what is happening here and how to avoid this?

Edit: Okey, here are the exception details if they help:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
  _HResult=-2003304445
  _message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980003
  HResult=-2003304445
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980003
  Source=PresentationCore
  ErrorCode=-2003304445
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap.CopyCommon(RenderTargetBitmap sourceBitmap)
InnerException:
```

Comment: In the exception helper dialog, there's a link at the bottom that says "copy exception details to the clipboard".  **Do that**.  Then add it to your question in an [edit].

Comment: I doubt that, but maybe this made something more clear about the problem? I'm thinking that it's because that gif is long, it has many layers, multiply it by 50 and you have a ton of layers. I have searched how to combine those gifs into one big gif, but it seems that it's very, very complex for gifs